# phonegap/ionic - $scope inside of click function not updating

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a simple setup where I want to click a button and get the data from an input control.  The problem is that the $scope variable inside of the click function keeps the same value as when the code is first run.  Everything works exactly as planned when I create a fiddle in the web.

HTML

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
        <input type="text" ng-model="authenticationCode">
        <br>
        <button class="button" ng-click="authenticate()">Authenticate</button>
        <br>
        <span>Auth info: {{authinfo}}</span>
        <br>
        <span>authenticationCode - {{authenticationCode}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.authenticationCode = 'TESTER';
$scope.authenticate = function(){
        var t = $scope.authenticationCode;
    $scope.authinfo = t;
    };
}
```

[Fiddle of the code working in web](http://jsfiddle.net/VtoCorleone/U3pVM/5732/)

When I run this in PhoneGap

- Screen loads with 'TESTER' in input box
- Screen loads with 'TESTER' as value for "authenticationCode -"
- Changing 'TESTER' in the input to 'CHANGED' updates "authenticationCode -" to 'CHANGED'
- Clicking 'Authenticate' puts the value 'TESTER' as "Auth info:"

I don't know why $scope.authenticationCode is not updating it's value in the authenticate function.  I'm also not sure why this works in the web and I'm having issues in PhoneGap with Ionic.

Comment: [Here is a CodePen that attempts to recreate the situation using Ionic](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/qeLFc).  Please try this out in PhoneGap. I think the issue you have may be due to using primitives.  Please read this - [If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong!](http://zcourts.com/2013/05/31/angularjs-if-you-dont-have-a-dot-youre-doing-it-wrong/)

Comment: Yup.  That was it.  If you can wrap that up and edit your answer, I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks.

Comment: Hey that's great we figured out the root cause of the issue.  I updated my answer providing the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue may be occurring because primitives are being used in the `TodoCtrl`, please try this -

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" ng-model="input.authenticationCode">
    </label>
    <br>
    <button class="button" ng-click="authenticate()">Authenticate</button>
    <br><br>
    <span>Auth info: {{input.authInfo}}</span>
    <br>
    <span>authenticationCode - {{input.authenticationCode}}</span>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
.controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.input = {
        authenticationCode: 'TESTER',
        authInfo: ''
    };

    $scope.authenticate = function() {
        $scope.input.authInfo = $scope.input.authenticationCode;
        console.log('authInfo: ' + $scope.input.authInfo);
    };
}]);
```

[Here is a CodePen of the above](http://codepen.io/rossmartin/pen/qeLFc)

Comment: Thanks for the reply but unfortunately neither of them worked.  Using $watch, authinfo had no value in it when pressing the button.  Using $timeout, I got the same results as my original issue.  The value is still 'TESTER'.

Comment: @VtoCorleone I updated the answer to not use primitive values, this could be an inheritance issue.  What do you see for `newValue` in the `console.log` within the `$scope.$watch`?

Comment: @VtoCorleone Also, please note that I changed `authinfo` to `authInfo`.

Comment: console.log doesn't print anything to logcat in the $watch function.

Comment: @VtoCorleone Did you update your markup to be `<input type="text" ng-model="input.authenticationCode">` instead of `<input type="text" ng-model="authenticationCode">`?

Comment: Copy and paste your $watch example - console.log prints out 'TESTER' when the button is pushed no matter what is in the input box.  
Copy and paste your $timeout example - nothing prints if I put a console.log in the $timeout function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55078/discussion-between-ross-and-vtocorleone).